# IntelliJ's breakpoints snaps in and out of "no executable code found at line"

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug and run a Jetty project in `IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3`

I marked few lines with break points (and they are marked correctly in red circle).

Than I start the Jetty server in debug mode, and at some point, as the server is spinning up, some of the break point lines turn to the gray "no entry" sign with the error of

> no executable code found at line ....

And as I stop the Jetty, the break points snaps back to red circle.

I tried to (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872778/5458827) for example):

- re-import the maven dependencies
- rebuilding the project
- run `mvn clean install`
- File -> "Invalidate Caches & Restart"

Yet, nothing is solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after some frustrating hours, I was able to make it work, when updating the `edit configuration` screen and added the relevant `build Artifact` to the `Before launch...`:

[image]

Comment: The issue may happen when you build project not by IDE but by some external builder (e.g. Maven) that generates different bytecode that IDE expects to have for the file you open in Editor. To be sure that the source file is always in sync with it's compiled version it is advised to build by IDE unless there is some specific reason to use Maven.